# Set the same font for all component Java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe, jpanel

I want to set a specific font for all component in a `JPanel` but I prefer that the question is still more general and not limited to the JPanel. How can I set the font to a list of component in a container (JFrame or JPanel)?

Answer (score 20):

Here is a simple method that allows you to specify Font to the whole components tree under any Container (or just a simple Component, doesn't matter):

```
public static void changeFont ( Component component, Font font )
{
    component.setFont ( font );
    if ( component instanceof Container )
    {
        for ( Component child : ( ( Container ) component ).getComponents () )
        {
            changeFont ( child, font );
        }
    }
}
```

Simply pass your panel and specific Font into this method and you will get all childs refactored aswell.

Comment: Awesome , its working great , I have changed your code bit like this , and its helping me , i am posting that code in the Answer

Answer (score 14):

**-** You can use `UIManager` to do this....

**Eg:**

```
public class FrameTest {

    public static void setUIFont(FontUIResource f) {
        Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = keys.nextElement();
            Object value = UIManager.get(key);
            if (value instanceof FontUIResource) {
                FontUIResource orig = (FontUIResource) value;
                Font font = new Font(f.getFontName(), orig.getStyle(), f.getSize());
                UIManager.put(key, new FontUIResource(font));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        setUIFont(new FontUIResource(new Font("Arial", 0, 20)));

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel("hello"));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test Title"));

        f.add(p);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use UIManager I change the font to the component throughout the application but I wan' t to change it only in a specific `JFrame` or `JPanel`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set the font values in [`UIManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) for the components you want to change. For example, you can set the font used for labels by doing:

```
Font labelFont = ... ;
UIManager.put("Label.font", labelFont);
```

Note that different look and feels (L&F) may have different properties for the `UIManager` class, so if you switch from one L&F to another, you may have issues.

Comment: If I use UIManager I change the font to the component throughout the application but I wan' t to change it only in a specific `JFrame` or `JPanel`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from Mikle Grains Answer
I used his code to increase the font of each component in percentage by getting the old fontsize

```
 public static void changeFont(Component component, int fontSize) {
    Font f = component.getFont();
    component.setFont(new Font(f.getName(),f.getStyle(),f.getSize() + fontSize));
    if (component instanceof Container) {
        for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
            changeFont(child, fontSize);
        }
    }
}
```