# How to create a java.awt.Font object available for the whole application instance in java?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, uimanager

I need to create a `java.awt.Font` object for my project and it needs to be available for the whole application. I cannot install the font to the system and any help regarding creating the font object in the runtime is needed.
My JDK is 1.7.0_17 and my code is the following.

```
try {
    Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DL-Paras...ttf"));
    jLabel1.setFont(f);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can objects be called like the system properties throughout the application instance?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thank you all, I got the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Don't know about duplicate, but a nice answer none-the-less +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer  It is the `registerFont(Font)` method I was thinking that makes this a duplicate.  Once registered, it can be used like any other `Font`.  Of course, if the OP is thinking more along the lines of setting a font in lust one place and have it used for components thereafter, they need to tweak the Pluggable Look & Feel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson After re-reading the question a few dozen more times, I think you're right

Comment: please isn't about UIManager `....available for the whole application instance in...`

Comment: @isu3ru are you meaning that your Font could be used, changed, applied for all JComponents (`jLabel1.setFont(f);`), ???

Comment: Thank you all, for the support.
@AndrewThompson, @MadProgrammer, @mKorbel and all. 

the code snippet from the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font) did the trick.
`GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);` 

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I found the answer here on this post. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730230/set-the-same-font-for-all-component-java

Thanks again. This is the best support website ever!